# What does "write failed: No space left on device" mean?

Tags: php, diskspace

I am getting these errors on my site, yet i haven't changed any code or anything, so I don't why this is happening.

```
Warning: Unknown(): write failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown(): Failed to write session data (files). 
Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: I've retitled and retagged your question -- the error is coming from PHP, not MySQL.  Be glad for that, you totally don't want to deal with MySQL after an out of space condition.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming you're hosting your site on a shared hosting provider
Basicly the error means that the server has run out of disk space, so it can't complete the sql commands

Just call/email the hosting company and they should fix it for you

Comment: @Michael, ..unless you've went over your own space limit - in that case you'll have to fix it yourself (free up some space in the db).

Comment: I really don't use alot of space, so I doubt the problem is caused by me, I'll send a mail to the hosting company about it.
Thank you.

Comment: It's not only the files you upload there, for example very large log-files may cause the problem.

Comment: `/tmp` may be a completely seperate file system and have run out of space, even if the rest of the web tree has plenty of space left.

Comment: why does this answer accepted? or "call your hoster" is an universal answer to any web sh*t happened?

Comment: this cannot be the only answer because this just happened to me and I have 18Gb left on the main disk and enough space on other partitions. I cant explain it at the moment.

Comment: just clearing the cache resolved my issues symfony: `php bin/console cache:clear` and Laravel see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48419624/how-to-clear-cache-in-laravel) or delete the content of the var directory.

Answer (score 7):

In a shared hosting, change the location where sessions are saved.

Create the directory: /public_htm/tmp, give the permissions (777) <- then you have to tune it (for security).

Create a file .htaccess in the directory /public_htm/tmp with:

```
order deny, allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

And in your PHP script, on top (in your front controller):

```
session_save_path(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/public_html/tmp');
```

Important: You must be added before session_start()

Check this with a script:

```
<?php
session_save_path(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/public_html/tmp');
session_start();
$_SESSION['Text'] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis nunc eu ut elit eget adipiscing facilisis turpis."
phpinfo();
?>
```

Check if changed the directive "session.save_path"

Answer (score 3):

> df -h

to look /tmp space left.

If /tmp is over 100%

> cd /tmp
>
> rm -r ./* -f

And you can save sessions again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have partitions (`df -h`) and the one you're hosting the mysql is full.

Move the folders that are more size consuming to the new partition, in my case `mv /var/mail /home`, and create a symink `sudo ln -s /home/mail mail`. You can move mysql itself.

Answer (score 0):

try use this command on console:

php bin/console cache:clear