# Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_870ebb463f8178dddba51ec6c0d03f3f, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on

Tags: mysql, server

i have built a social networking site. But after uploading it on the server and running it. It is showing this error sometimes on the login page and then people are no able to login. I have hosted two sites on my server.

FUll Error

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_870ebb463f8178dddba51ec6c0d03f3f, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28) in/home/jus68185/public_html/xyz.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412435/what-does-write-failed-no-space-left-on-device-mean - maybe this could help...

Comment: sir, they are not solving the problem...since i have hosted two websites on my server i guess the problem could be solved by session.save_path