# How to clear cache in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have added css file in master-blade.php like this

```
   <link href="{{ url(mix('css/app.css')) }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

In view the path of css file looks like this.

```
    <link href="******/css/app.css?id=43965480df345823e8e0" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now i am changing the css in app.css file but it does not reflect on web page.The problem is due to the id in path of css file. How can i do the changes in css file.

Comment: Run `php artisan cache:clear` and  `php artisan view:clear` from your project path directory.

Comment: Or you run `npm run dev` or `npm run prod` to generate/update the JS and CSS

Comment: This is not a duplicate. It's a totally different question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to run `npm run dev` on your development server and `npm run prod` on your production server, to generate/update the JS and CSS.

If you want clear all cache, stored in /storage/cache:

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

And to clear route cache:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

To clear view cache:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

try artisan command-

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Answer (score 1):

This command clears all cache:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear view cache, do this:

```
php artisan view:clear
```

You also can clear [all Laravel cache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37259162/1227923).

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you which type of cache you want to clear. Here is all the types of commands:

**It clears app cache**

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

**It clears view cache**

```
php artisan view:clear
```

**It clears route cache**

```
php artisan route:clear
```

**It clears config cache**

```
php artisan config:clear
```

**It clears event cache**

```
php artisan event:clear
```

**It removes compiled services and packages files**

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

**It clears all caches at once**

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```